# JxBrowser JSFunction.invoke with object

Tags: object, jxbrowser

I want to invoke a JavaScript function from Java, passing to the function an Object.  What I hoped to do is something like:

`JSObject obj = new JSObject();
 obj.setString("property1", "value);
 obj.setNumber("property2", number);`

and pass the object to the JavaScript function via the JSFunction.invoke() method.  But JSObject apparently has no default constructor, nor methods like "setString". Ditto for JSONString.

I ended up using the Google GSon library to build a JSON string that I then passed to "new JSONString()". Do you have any better way?

I wish your documentation addressed this point instead of forcing me to invent this solution.  Not what I wanted to spend time on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code sample that demonstrates how to create an object and set some properties to it:

```
Browser browser = new Browser();

browser.executeJavaScript("function foo(object) { console.log(object.property1); }");

JSObject object = browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue("new Object()").asObject();
object.setProperty("property1", "value 1");
object.setProperty("property2", 15);

JSFunction function = browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue("window.foo")
        .asFunction();
function.invoke(null, object);
```